# How can I stop showing undefined values which come from handlebars in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to stop showing `undefined` values.

```
td>{{this.cost_price_currency}} {{this.cost_price}}</td>
```

If `{{this.cost_price_currency}}` is `undefined` `{{this.cost_price_currency}}` and `{{this.cost_price}}` not should be shown.

How Can solve this using `Javascript` or `Jquery`

Answer (score 0):

```
if(this.cost_price_currency === undefined) {
  this.cost_price = "";
  this.cost_price_currency = "";
}
```

https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/